# What is the php.ini setting that allows response outputs?

Tags: php

Much like asp.net's `<%=SomeVariable%>` how can i enable `<?php =SomeVariable ?>` ?

Currently my app only works if i do `<?php echo(SomeVariable) ?>`

Iam using php 5.1.6

Thanks

Comment: The actual syntax is <?= $someVariable not <?php= $someVariable

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're looking for [`short_open_tag`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)

Note that using short tags is generally considered bad practice because it reduces code portability.  It's best to use the standard `<?php echo "..."; ?>` as this will run regardless of server settings.

Comment: If im not mistaken short_open_tag setting allows for the short form directive <? DoSomething ?> to be used. It has nothing to do with 'echo' or '=' ?

Comment: @Th3Fix3r: You have to read the page he linked to: “Note: This directive also affects the shorthand `<?=`, which is identical to `<? echo`. Use of this shortcut requires short_open_tag to be on. But I wouldn’t use it for portability reasons.”

Answer (score -1):

Try not to use the ASP style open/close tags as there is a **[possibility](http://www.php.net/~derick/meeting-notes.html#remove-support-for-and-script-language-php-and-add-php-var)** that they will be deprecated in PHP 6.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, php has no `<?php=` syntax.  You either turn on short_open_tag and get `<?` **and** `<?=` or, you do it the sadly, proper way and do `<?php print(); ?>` or `<?php echo();?>`.

Some people (and frameworks) do a little syntactic sugar like this:

```
function p($toPrint) {
  print($toPrint);  
}
```

and that allows:

```
<?php p($message) ?>
```

But short tags really aren't desirable.  Possible future deprication is one reason, but the other is that `<?` is the start of an XML declaration as well, and that can cause problems when you're doing this for XHTML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
```

you'll get a nasty PHP error.